# How to Install a tomcat server and xampp server separately into my pc?

Tags: apache, tomcat, installation, xampp

I am facing a problem with installing tomcat. I have a xampp server which already installed my windows 7 pc. Now I want to install tomcat server. Xampp and Tomcat both are apache server. I get many tutorials which show me how to integrate tomcat and xampp together. But actually I want to install the tomcat separately in a different folder. Is it possible? If possible then what I have to do? And how will I be able to run the both server? If not possible then please suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install Tomcat ( Don't worry about the xampp installation.Keep it as it is )
Modify the file `server.xml` (located in `tomcat_installation_path\conf\` ) as follows
- Change the default port number i.e 8080
   ex: `Connector port=”8080″` to `Connector port=”8081″` 
 
because 8080 is used by xampp
[read more about changing default port number](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/)

Now when you start xamp you go to  `localhost:8080\`
 
and whenever you run tomcat you go to  `localhost:8081\`

Or you can do it in other-way round as well ( keep the default port number of Tomcat and change the Xampp's port number )

Answer (score 0):

Q) your windows server is running with XAMP, now you want install the tomcat server on the same Windows server is there any problems will be there ?

Ans) there is no problems will be occur if XAMP already present in windows server, while installing the tomcat server you have to change the port numbers
1) Shutdown port
2) Server port
3) connector port
4) API Port

only port changes apart from everything normal installation.

now your windows Server will run both XAMP and Tomcat and also you can access the xamp-tomcat on 8080 and new tomcat on new port.